# $L(s,\chi)=1$ for non trivial Dirichlet character modulo a polynomial of degree $1$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields, dirichlet-series

Let $m(x)\in \Bbb F_q[X]$ be a monic polynomial of degree $1$.

Show that for every non-trivial Dirichlet character modulo $m$ we have: 
$L(s,\chi)=1$.

I have seen a theorem that states that if $\chi$ is non trivial, then $L(s,\chi)$ is a polynomial in $q^{-s}$ of degree at most $deg(m)-1$. In my case, it means the degree is $0$, so $L(s,\chi) \in \Bbb F_q$. I still can't understand why it equals $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$L(T,\chi) = \sum_{f \in F_q[X]_{monic}} \chi(f) T^{\deg(f)} = \\ 
T^{\deg(1)} +  \sum_{a \in F_q[X]/(m)} \chi(a) \sum_{f \in F_q[X]_{monic}} T^{\deg(f m +a)}$$ Can you finish from there ?

Comment: Why is $L(T,\chi)=\sum_{f \; monic}\chi(f)T^{deg f}$ ? according to the definition I know: $L(T,\chi)=\sum_{f \; monic}\frac{\chi(f)}{|f|^T}$

Comment: @user401516 With $|f| = q^{\deg(f)}$ then $|f|^{-s} = T^{\deg(f)}$ where $T =q^{-s}$. We use the $q^{-s}$ notation only in the theory of global zeta functions. For local zeta functions we prefer to make clear they are power series in $T =q^{-s}$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. Why is $T^{deg(a)}=\sum_{f \; monic}T^{deg(fm+a)}$ ? sorry for being slow, pretty new to this subject.

Comment: $m$ is monic so any $h$ monic of degree $\ge m$ is of the form $h = fm+a$ with $deg(a) < \deg(m)$ and $f$ monic. That leaves us with $L(T,\chi)= \sum_{h \in F_q[X]_{monic}, \deg(h) < \deg(m)} \chi(h) T^{\deg(h)}+ \sum_{f \in F_q[X]_{monic}}  \sum_{a \in F_q[X]/(m)} \chi(fm+a) T^{\deg(f m +a)}$. Here $\deg(m) = 1$ so the first sum is easy. The second sum simplifies as $\chi(fm+a) = \chi(a)$. @user401516